# How to resolve java.lang.NullPointerException in scala?

Tags: java, scala

assume part of my code is like as:- 
where doc is List[Document] that contains stu_name and roll_number
sometimes stu_name and roll_name may be null.

I used Try to avoid null Pointer exception in first two lines.
but why I m getting again Null Pointer exception in "val myRow".

```
    val name= Try {Option.apply(doc.getFieldValue("stu_name"))}.getOrElse(null)
    val rollNumber ={Option.apply(doc.getFieldValue("roll_number"))}.getOrElse(null)

    val myRow = (
     doc.getFieldValue("ID").asInstanceOf[Int]   //can't be null
     name.getOrElse(null).toString,   //NullPointerException
     rollNumber.getOrElse(null).asInstanceOf[Int] //NullPointerException
    )

    .....
    .....
```

I m getting following error:

```
 [2016-01-14 22:40:16,896] WARN  o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager [] [akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/demeter] - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.29.23.136): java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.events.Monitoring$$anonfun$geteventTableReplicateDayFunc$1.apply(Monitoring.scala:75)
at com.test.events.Monitoring$$anonfun$geteventTableReplicateDayFunc$1.apply(Monitoring.scala:57)
at com.test.events.Monitoring$$anonfun$27.apply(Monitoring.scala:104)
at com.test.events.Monitoring$$anonfun$27.apply(Monitoring.scala:104)
```

I tried in console following but did not see any error:

```
scala> val a = Try (Option.apply("atar")).getOrElse(null)
a: Option[String] = Some(atar)
scala> a.getOrElse(null)
res16: String = atar

scala> val a = Try (Option.apply(null)).getOrElse(null)
a: Option[Null] = None
scala> a.getOrElse(null)
res17: Null = null
```

Comment: So is `doc` null, then?

Comment: doc can not be null. some fields are compulsory exist.

Comment: But are you *sure* about that?  Your stack trace doesn't fill in all of the details here.

Comment: yes. Sure..can't be null. I have added one more compulsory fields.

Comment: `name.getOrElse(null).toString` this is completely bad. `toString` on `null` does not exist.

Comment: I would suggest that you either work with Scala's `None` or `Failure`. The reason these were created in Scala is to do away with `null`s. If you're not comfortable working with those then at least provide default values which are non-null such as a blank string: `name.getOrElse("")`

Answer (score 1):

This is all wrong. By using `getOrElse(null)` you are basically removing all advantages to using an `Option` to begin with. Plus, generating much more complexity than needed.

You need to define what you will do if the values are null. This just keeps them as `Options` (`None` on null input):

```
val myRow = (
 doc.getFieldValue("ID").toInt,                         // Fails if null
 Option(doc.getFieldValue("stu_name")),                 // `None` if null   
 Option(doc.getFieldValue("roll_number")).map(_.toInt)  // `None` if null   
)
```

Or use default values:

```
val myRow = (
 doc.getFieldValue("ID").toInt,                          
 Option(doc.getFieldValue("stu_name")).getOrElse("default"),                 
 Option(doc.getFieldValue("roll_number")).map(_.toInt).getOrElse(0)  
)
```